# Where can the last FSTrim be seen as successful or not? (log files)

Tags: ssd, log, trim

I recently installed an SSD and AFAIK Ubuntu makes a weekly FSTrim on SSD's that support it.

Is there a log file of this trims?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no special log file and the command `fstrim` has usually no output without the `-v` switch if there is no error.

`/sbin/fstrim --all` is started via cron and the only thing you can see are the messages that `cron` writes into `/var/log/syslog`.

---

You could change the configuration in `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`.

- Open the file in your editor:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
  ```
- Add the `-v` switch

  ```
  /sbin/fstrim -v --all || true
  ```

  and you will have an output like this

  ```
  /: 182,2 MiB (191000576 bytes) trimmed
  ```

  in your `syslog`

Comment: So if there were errors on the last FSTrim then is on the syslog ?

Comment: Yes. That's right

Comment: Good then I just need CAT and GREP.
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep fstrim